# How can I use awk (or sed) to put data set labels onto each line of the data sets?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a bunch of data for different devices in a file and it's set up like this:

```
device: thing1

data1 data2 data3 data4

data1 data2 data3 data4

...

device: thing2

data1 data2 data3 data4

data1 data2 data3 data4

...
```

I need to format it like this:

```
thing1 data1 data2 data3 data4

thing1 data1 data2 data3 data4

...

thing2 data1 data2 data3 data4

thing2 data1 data2 data3 data4
```

I'm thinking awk is the way to go. The label "device:" appears every few hundred lines or so to indicate a data set from another device. So, I can match on that and put the second field into a variable. The problem is that I'm not sure how to match on it without excluding all the lines with the data. Here's what I've got so far:

```
-bash-4.2$ awk '/device:/{device=$2; print device, $0;}' data_sets.txt | head -n 10

thing2 device: thing2

thing3 device: thing3

thing6 device: thing6

thing7 device: thing7

another_thing0 device: another_thing0

another_thing1 device: another_thing1

thing2 device: thing2

thing3 device: thing3

thing6 device: thing6

thing7 device: thing7
```

Comment: please update the question to show the (`awk`?) code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code; don't limit yourself to *`single-line operations`*; there's absolutely nothing wrong with a multi-line 'operation' (and keep in mind that if for some reason you *need* a single-line solution, most multi-line solutions can be reformatted into a single-line ... or stored in a file and the file referenced in a single-line solution)

Comment: My attempts have resulted in failure; the commands have returned nothing valuable. This is why I'm asking the forum. But, I don't want to appear too proud, so here's the command I was trying (constant_fieldname is "device:" : awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="device:"} {split($1,a," "); label[a[2]]; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++); END{for (each in label) print label $0}' data_file.txt

Comment: If I use instead   awk '/device:/{device=$2; print device $0;}' data_file.txt    then I nearly get what I'm looking for. The only problem there is that I'm only matching on the line with the label. I need to put the value of $2 on all the other lines following the label line.

Comment: please update the question with your code attempts and the results; not everyone is going to read through comments trying to piece together the bigger picture; also, code is  bit harder to read when buried in comments

Comment: also consider updating the question so that your sample data matches your code, eg, replace `constant_fieldname` with `device` if that's what really in the file; also consider providing actual file contents (eg, can `thingN` contain white space) and describe the column delimiter (single space? tab? multiple spaces?) of the data line

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was trying to keep it generalized. I guess it does make it kinda murky when I do that. Does the original post look better?

Comment: somewhat better, though having your code attempt generate output that doesn't match up with the provided sample input could be confusing (eg, `thing7` doesn't show up anywhere in the sample input so not sure how your code could have generated the `thing7` lines); net result, less confusion occurs when sample outputs (expected, actual) match the sample input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `device:` lines contain only 2 space-delimited strings (eg, device name does not contain white space)
- do not print the `device:` lines
- if there are blank lines then skip them
- default output field separator (`OFS`) of a single space is sufficient for the resulting output

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/^device:/ { device=$2; next }          # make note of our new device name; skip to next line of input
NF > 1     { print device,$0 }          # if line is not blank/empty then print the label and the current line of input
' data_file.txt
```

This generates:

```
thing1 data1 data2 data3 data4
thing1 data1 data2 data3 data4
thing2 data1 data2 data3 data4
thing2 data1 data2 data3 data4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e "s/^\(.*\)/constant_fieldname \1/" filename
```

You could try something like this, to add something at the begging of each row

Comment: That succeeds in putting constant_fieldname at the left of every line, which isn't what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to put the variable label, thing1, at the beginning of each line. Then, at some point later in the file, there's a new data set called thing2. The script needs to store thing1 and set that in each line that follows. Same for thing2 and thing3, etc.

Comment: This is just an example of how to do what you want. You cannot do what you want in one line as far as I know. You need some logic to go with it

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^constant_fieldname: \S+$/{h;d};G;s/^(.*)\n\S+: (\S+)$/\2 \1/' file
```

Copy the constant into the hold space and then delete that line.

For all other lines, append the constant to the current line and using substitution re-arrange the format.